# An alternate word for a feeling of unbelonging

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Do we have a word, phrase or an idiom  that means '**torn between worlds**' or **'don't know where I belong**'?

Contextual example : 
When you're torn between your school friends and college friends but don't feel at home with the companies of both. But you want to be a part of both sometimes, to get the best of two worlds, which almost never happens.

Comment: Hello! Please provide more context. A short description will be enough. Could you explain the situation and how you would use this expression or term. A sentence where the idiom would fit. This question risks getting a mountain load of unrelated answers or none at all. My bet is on the latter.

Comment: In Italian I might have suggested *Non essere né carne né pesce* (to be neither fish nor meat) but this is an English website.

Comment: I've added context. Please do check. Your Italian phrase is close to what it feels like, but an English one would be better, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 17th century [English idiom](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neither_fish_nor_fowl) could fit, Wiktionary says:

> **neither fish nor fowl**
>
> (idiomatic) Something or someone which is not easily categorized; something or someone that does not rightly belong or fit well in a given group or situation

Alternatively, [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/neither-one-thing-nor-the-other) suggest

> **neither one thing nor the other**
>   Not clearly either of two things: *Sam stands on the cusp, neither one thing nor the other*

I do like the term *cusp* which I think fits in with the OP's description. He or she may be on the cusp of adulthood, emotionally and/or physically.

**Conflicted,** describes the emotion.

> confused or ​worried because you cannot ​choose between very different ​ideas, ​feelings, or ​beliefs, and do not ​know what to do or ​believe
>
> [Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conflicted)

Comment: Neither fish nor fowl explained the context. Conflict was the perfect word I had been looking for, it portrays the emotion perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

You could try "displaced" or "expatriated."  Also, "ostracized" or "shunned."
I hope these ideas help.

Comment: Your answer would be improved by indicating *why* you believe these words would be appropriate, for example, by providing a full explanation, dictionary definitions, suitable examples, and other support. StackExchange answers are expected to be definitive. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the feeling of not belonging to a place or a group of people  can be described by he idiomatic expression:.

***[be like a fish out of water](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+like+a+fish+out+of+water):***

> - to feel awkward because you are not familiar with a situation or because you are very different from the people around you.
>
>   - *All the other children in the school had rich, middle-class parents, and she was beginning to feel like a fish out of water.*

(Cambridge Idioms Dictionary)